# Where to keep PHP files while doing Android programming in eclipse?

Tags: php, android, eclipse

I'm doing android programing and I am using Eclipse like most people. I'm starting to do some MySQL database access, and now am using PHP scripts on the server.

How can I organize the PHP scripts so that they come up in the tree list in Eclipse, but don't affect compiling in any way? Editing them in Eclipse would be nice, but I'm more concerned at this point having it in the same project. That way it is easy to access them to make changes, and that way I can just back up the project directory and have all the files that I need.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend to mix Android source code and PHP source code in one project. Seperating them in two eclipse projectes provides overview and doesn't force you to make a non-standard directory structure.

For answering your question: You can add exclusion patterns at the Source preferences of the project's build path settings.